# R CMD build - ERROR copying to build directory failed

Tags: r

I can't seem to build a new package that I created (not much other than the R generated skeleton).  Here's the error message.  How can I view more details about the ERROR?  And where is the "build directory" specified?

```
Loading required package: digest
* checking for file 'E:\R\mypkg/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'mypkg':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
 ERROR
copying to build directory failed
```

Comment: Try [searching on rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=%22copying+to+build+directory+failed%22&sa=Search&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=www.rseek.org%252F#735).  My guess is that there's an issue creating the directory.

Comment: @Joshua - did use rseek but in this case the message is too generic and it seems people hit this message in a variety of scenarios.  "copying to build directory failed" - copying what?  and what is the "build directory"?  Anyways, I'm working through some issues with R CMD check.  perhaps after those are resolved then it will work.  I'd still like to know what the "build directory" is.  Do you know?

Comment: Take a look at the code in build.R (line 765-ish).  Copying everything from the package; the "build directory" is a temporary directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that I didn't have RTools installed http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/

Comment: This is discussed in [R Installation and Administration, Appendix D: The Windows Toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset).